# PHP: Check if link is from extern

Tags: php, security, hyperlink

I am programming a new homepage and I noticed a scenario I have never worried before:
Eg. Friendsystem:
I can add a person as a friend on my homepage and I do that using a link e.g.(index.php?action=friends&do=add&user=1)
Now: A random person could make a shortend link with it and post it somewhere. So if another person clicks on the link (not knowing what is behind it) it executes the friendrequest on my homepage.
POST requests won't solve the problem. So how do you manage this possible security bug?
Hash/Tokens?

Thanks
Erik

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please read [What topics can I ask about](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [How to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) And [the perfect question](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/) And [how to create a Minimal, Complete and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: "POST requests won't solve the problem." Why not? "So if another person clicks on the link (not knowing what is behind it)", he/she should be logged in to be able to add a friend. "Hash/Tokens?" for example, yes

Answer (score 1):

A GET request MUST NOT ever modify data; that's what POST is made for and it *will* solve the problem.

As a general rule of thumb:

- If you add, modify or delete data - use POST (or PUT, DELETE, PATCH; although these are overkill for simple PHP web apps)
- If you *only* display data, then use GET.